# Cordova angular app (reverse) proxy configuration

Tags: angular, android-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

We have wrapped Angular project with Cordova, but **proxy configuration** to forward the request present inside **"proxy.conf.json"** file of angular project has not been moved to Cordova www folder.

We need to call web service deployed in AWS from Cordova wrapped angular application.

Please let us know how can we call webservice deployed in AWS from Cordova angular app

Comment: Did you use a parameter something like : --proxy-config proxy.conf.json for serving the project

Comment: Hi Tech Explorer. Please show the code you tried. That will help readers know how to answer your question.